# Issue with Gwt-Radio Button

Tags: gwt, radio-button

I am using same group name for two of my GWT-RadioButtons. When I click one of these, another one gets unchecked, which is good. But programmatically (when i do debug) the other radio button value is still remained as 'true' . As per my requirement it should be false. I am thinking that it is problem of GWT-RadioButton Group concept.

Does this problem of GWT - RadioButton?

The below is code snippet

```
indiaRadioBtn.setValue(true);     
  indiaRadioBtn.addClickHandler(new IndianRadioClickHandler());     
  othersRadioBtn.addClickHandler(new InternationalRadioClickHandler());     

    if (contactInfo != null) {     
    if (contactInfo.getPostalAddress().getCountry() != null) {    
      othersRadioBtn.setValue(true);      
    }     

    if (indiaRadioBtn.getValue()) {    
      index = -1;    
      for (StateOrProvince stateOrProvince : StateOrProvince.values()) {    
        index++;
        if ((contactInfo.getPostalAddress().getState() != null)    
            && contactInfo.getPostalAddress().getState().equals(stateOrProvince.name())) {   
          stateListBox.setSelectedIndex(index);     
        }    
      }    
    } else {    
          //some code  }
```

class IndianRadioClickHandler implements ClickHandler {

```
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    //newOrUpdateContactInfoFormPanel.clear();
    ContactInfo contactInfo = getSelectedContactInfo();

    /**
     * Used same panel and elements for both addresses, so clearing address for Indian.
     */
    if (contactInfo != null) {
      if (contactInfo.getPostalAddress().getCountry() != null
          || title.equals("Create New Address")) {
        contactInfo = null;
      }
    }
    newOrUpdateContactInfoFormPanel.add(getCompleteFormPanel(contactInfo));
  }
}


if contactInfo != null then it is executing that loop, i am setting  othersRadioBtn.setValue(true);
```

So my other radio button is should set to false according to  group concept.. but it is not doing its job.

Comment: Can you please show us the code ?

Comment: i added my code above.

Comment: add the code of new IndianRadioClickHandler()